# How to cycle and store values into an ArrayList, whichj is to be passed to JSP for display

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have to be able to store data in a new object, that I am getting from a complex object where each item is held in a List.

The hierarchy is the following:
1) libraryId (Library)
2) bookId (book)
3) pageId (page)
4) wordId (word)

- A library can have zero to many books. Each book is unique and can have zero to many pageId's, if there is a page, each pageId can have zero to many wordId's.

I have the data, but I need to cycle through each item and put into an object - ArrayList or similar - so I can pass off to another class, which is expecting a List. In the next class, the data is to be presented in a JSP data table.

I have the following classed to do this:

```
class Library{ 
  int libraryId; 
  ArrayList<Book> books; 
} 

class Book { 
  int bookId; 
  ArrayList<Page> pages; 
} 

class Page { 
  int pageId; 
  ArrayList<Word> words; 
} 

class Word { 
  int wordId; 
}
```

I have started to do it like this:

```
Book book = new Book(); // create Book object 
ArrayList<Page> pages = new ArrayList<Page>; 
pages.add(new Page()); // add first page 
pages.add(new Page()); // add next page 
book.setPages(pages); // set reference to pages for book
```

I have tried this.I am not sure I have it working correctly. This is how i have done it, based on the above answer. I the the same classes etc.

I have the following data example:

1 Book, which has 1 page, that page has 8 words. I have another book, which has 2 pages, each page has 6 words. I hope this makes sense.

Based on the above example, how to do I write this code, and how to I then retrieve the data back out too? The aim is that I pass this to a JSP, then retieve this out into a table using JSTL . Any help with this, to retrieve this data would also be helpful.

Comment: it's unclear what is the data you want to display and what do you want to retrieve. show us the JSP code that you tried to implement and where exactly you got stuck

Comment: Could you explain what you want the result to be in your data example?

Comment: My aim is, I want to create a list of books in my library object. - This will contain all the data, as the example: **1 Book, which has 1 page, that page has 8 words. I have another book, which has 2 pages, each page has 6 words.** I am using `<c:forEach var="page" items="${book.pages}"> <!-- print page --> </c:forEach>` in the JSP. My problem in the implementation code to put the data example into the classes I have. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Daniel I want the library object to hold the books in the book arrayList. then within that arraylist, I want it to hold the pages in the page arrayList. Then within that, I want it to hold the words in the words arrayList

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such :)

Comment: The question as it stands is somewhat broad--you appear to know how to create the objects you need (although id generation remains a mystery). Are you asking how to get a list to the JSP (`request.setAttribute`)? How to use JSTL to display (`<c:forEach>`)?

Comment: Hi @DaveNewton for work im affaid :) I need to pass a list to the JSP. I think passing to the JSP is ok, reading in the forEach is ok, but I am struggling putting this data example above into the objects above and how to read again, so I can see it is working ok.

Comment: @babb Since it's for work, please show what you have so far, describe the environment in which it will be deployed, etc. so we can diagnose what's wrong with your code. Also, since it's for professional development, I hope you're following best practices and providing the getters/setters for your JavaBeans, which JSTL expects to be present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on your framework.  Are you are a glutton for punishment and using straight JSP, if so, take a look at <jsp:useBean> or use a scriptlet (ugh...) to populate the "book" variable.

Otherwise, it will be very framework dependent.  Something like spring would be:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
  @RequestMapping(...)
  public ModelAndView processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response) {
      Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      Book book = ...;
      model.put("book", book);
      return new ModelAndView("viewbook", model);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, I now need to iterate over this data in the JSP. if I pass in the book object, how can I access and present the lower level data, inside the book, is pages arraylist data, and inside that is work data? I was using foreach, but I dont know up to access the inside elements of book

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
<c:forEach var="book" items="${bookList}">
                        <tr>                        
                            <td>${book.id}</td>
                            <td>${book.name}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <c:forEach var="page" items="${book.pages}">
                            <tr>                        
                                <td>${page.id}</td>
                                <td>${page.name}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>                    
                    </c:forEach>
```